# Showing the positivity of the measure $(E+y) \cap F$ for every positive measurable sets $E$ and $F$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that $E, F \subseteq \Bbb R$ are two measurable sets with positive measure. I want to show that there exists $y \in \Bbb R$ such that $m[(E+y) \cap F]>0$ ($m$ being the Lebesgue measure).

The idea that comes to my mind is that there are open covers for $E$ and $F$ named {$I_E$}$_n$ and {$I_F$}$_n$ respectively. From Heine–Borel theorem {$I_E$}$_n$ and {$I_F$}$_n$ have finite subcovers {$I'_E$}$_n$ and {$I'_F$}$_n$ respectively. From positivity of the measures of $E$ and $F$ we can conclude that there exist $I'_E$$_n$$_0$ in {$I'_E$}$_n$ and $I'_F$$_n$$_0$ in {$I'_F$}$_n$ such that m[$I'_E$$_n$$_0$]$>0$ and m[$I'_F$$_n$$_0$]$>0$. If m[$I'_E$$_n$$_0$ $\cap$ $I'_F$$_n$$_0$]>$0$, there is nothing more to prove. But, if $I'_E$$_n$$_0$ $\cap$ $I'_F$$_n$$_0$= $\emptyset$ there are two cases:  if  $inf$ ($I'_E$$_n$$_0$) <  $inf$ ($I'_F $$_n$$_0$) then let $y$=$inf$($I'_F$$_n$$_0$)$-$  $inf$ ($I'_E $$_n$$_0$) and if $inf$ ($I'_F$$_n$$_0$) <  $inf$ ($I'_E $$_n$$_0$) then let $y$=$inf$($I'_E$$_n$$_0$)$-$  $inf$ ($I'_F $$_n$$_0$).

Please help me and say if my thought is correct.